Problems capturing the formControlName of a dynamic form generated through JSON using angular 16
I'm trying to capture data from a dynamic form using Angular's reactive forms, but since the formControlNames are dynamic I can't configure them in the component's FormBuilder. How could I configure the formControlName in the ts file of the component to later store them in the database.
<div class="row">
      <!-- Three Folders -->
      <div *ngIf="showForm" formArrayName="items">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <div class="card border-dark mt-2 mb-4" *ngFor="let val of modelsaved">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ val.fld_name }}
              <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let iter of val.formfield; let i = index">
                <label>{{ iter.label }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="{{ iter.type }}" name="{{ iter.label }}"
                  [formControlName]="i">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" (click)="saveTemplate()"><i
                class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>
              Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- More 3 fields -->
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
        <div *ngIf="!showForm" formArrayName="items">
          <div class="card border-dark mt-2 mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ objInfo.adm }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let item of modelsaved; let i = index">
              <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="{{ item.type }}" name="{{ item.label }}"
              [formControlName]="i">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" (click)="saveTemplate()"><i
                class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>
              Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

I'm trying to capture data from a dynamic form using Angular's reactive forms, but since the formControlNames are dynamic I can't configure them in the component's FormBuilder. How could I configure the formControlName in the ts file of the component to later store them in the database.
